# Property value lost on async waterfall

Tags: node.js, express, node-async

I am trying to mock an express response object in order to perform some unit tests. My mocked response objects looks like this so far:

```
module.exports.responseHelper = {
    response: "",
    send : function(val){
        this.response = val;
    }
}
```

My problem is that if I pass this object to a method like this:

```
var async = require('async');

exports.sample = function (req, res) {
    async.waterfall([
        function(callback){
            callback(null, res);
        },
        function(res, callback){
            callback(null, res);
        },
        function(res, callback){
            callback(null, res);
        }
    ], function (err, res) {
        console.log("res before: " + res.response);
        res.send("something4");
        console.log("res after: " + res.response);
    });
};
```

Calling it like this:

```
var route = require("../routes/testing");
var response = require("./requestHelper").responseHelper;

var req = {
    params: {
        someID: 1
    }
}
route.sample(req, response);
console.log("final res: " + response.response);
```

The response.response value is always just "" (empty string)

Ideally I would not like to change the route implementation but I want to be able to get whatever value is passed to send at the end of the waterfall.

Comment: Started thinking that this is async so maybe I need some extra logic before asking for response...

Comment: I tried your code (copy/pasted to 3 separate files as you have identified above), and it works fine for me.  I see `res before: `
`res after: something4`.  So what you have above is correct, don't know if you have additional processing that is messing things up.

Comment: I edited the code...it is on the console.log("final res: " + response.response); where empty value is printed...and I am guessing it is because async actually runs in an async way.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  The `final res` output would occur prior to the work done through all those callbacks.  If you wanted it to occur after the `sample` was complete, you could include a callback there (or promise) -- perhaps calling it somewhere around your `res after` statement.